# App Is Crashing in Adhoc only? On Debug Mode running fine

Tags: debugging, crash, adhoc

```
  May 25 00:17:43 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[887] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
May 25 00:17:43 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[887] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/BB467DEE-061F-4A6C-8F75-F88F153BC4A0 [69] (sandbox)
May 25 00:17:43 unknown JulieRowe[887] <Warning>: Device token recived :- a0c4c5a4fa58b09de64b9c97e83cc92d352e3e10563d03b835dfc3eaf187bb14
May 25 00:17:43 unknown JulieRowe[887] <Error>: libMobileGestalt computeUniqueDeviceID: total time for bb to return imei: 0
May 25 00:17:43 unknown JulieRowe[887] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: author_id)'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x3729788f 0x34f9c259 0x37297789 0x372977ab 0x3720468b 0x3951 0x4041 0x3119860b 0x311990dd 0x36033af9 0x3726b523 0x3726b4c5 0x3726a313 0x371ed4a5 0x371ed36d 0x339ac439 0x30f99cd5 0x2c89 0x2c48)
May 25 00:17:43 unknown UIKitApplication:com.julierowe.authorapp[0xe204][887] <Notice>: terminate called throwing an exception
May 25 00:17:44 unknown ReportCrash[888] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process JulieRowe[887]
> 
May 25 00:17:44 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.julierowe.authorapp[0xe204]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6
May 25 00:17:44 unknown SpringBoard[51] <Warning>: Application 'Julie Rowe' exited abnormally with signal 6: Abort trap: 6
May 25 00:17:44 unknown ReportCrash[888] <Error>: libMobileGestalt computeUniqueDeviceID: total time for bb to return imei: 0
May 25 00:17:44 unknown ReportCrash[888] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/JulieRowe_2012-05-25-001743_Bob-Eveleth.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

This is  a device console log which i have got from xcode 4.3.2 organizer. But I am surprised App is running fine under Debug profile but under adhoc it crashing.

Comment: I have got the Solution about this problem.Thanks Byte

Comment: I want to share this problem solution, as from the log i got app is crashing from this reason(setting null value), but why not crashing in debug why in Adhoc.So when i searched thoroughly, i got my device was was registering for push notification in delegate method "- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken " and in this that null value was setting and this method didn't call in debug mode.it calls in adhoc only.

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819310/in-app-restore-works-fine-on-debug-but-crashes-on-adhoc-in-iphone-sdk