# In-app Restore works fine on Debug but crashes on AdHoc in iPhone sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, in-app-purchase, adhoc

My app is getting crashed when I clicked on Restore button clicked(AdHoc version) but same app is working fine in debug mode. My code:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

Crash report:

```
Nov  6 23:19:04 LHD-iPod5 backupd[1815] <Warning>: INFO: Account changed (enabled=0, accountID=(null))
Nov  6 23:19:04 LHD-iPod5 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore: operation failed (pid: 1815 sel: 23 ret: e00002f0)
Nov  6 23:19:04 LHD-iPod5 profiled[1816] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service starting...
Nov  6 23:19:04 LHD-iPod5 itunesstored[90] <Warning>: Could not load library [22]
Nov  6 23:19:04 LHD-iPod5 securityd[78] <Error>:  CFPropertyListReadFromFile file file:///Library/Keychains/accountStatus.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)
Nov  6 23:19:04 LHD-iPod5 securityd[78] <Notice>: item SecDbItemDoUpdate replaced O,genp,EEF8647C,L,cku,apple,1272,acct,svce,v_Data,20131106174027.105945Z,F7768B61 with O,genp,EEF8647C,L,cku,apple,1272,acct,svce,v_Data,20131106174904.733739Z,0A75C458 in <SecDbConnection rw open>
Nov  6 23:19:04 LHD-iPod5 securityd[78] <Error>:  CFPropertyListReadFromFile file file:///Library/Keychains/accountStatus.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)
Nov  6 23:19:04 LHD-iPod5 securityd[78] <Error>:  CFPropertyListReadFromFile file file:///Library/Keychains/accountStatus.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)
Nov  6 23:19:04 LHD-iPod5 securityd[78] <Error>:  CFPropertyListReadFromFile file file:///Library/Keychains/accountStatus.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)
Nov  6 23:19:04 LHD-iPod5 securityd[78] <Error>:  CFPropertyListReadFromFile file file:///Library/Keychains/accountStatus.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)
Nov  6 23:19:04 LHD-iPod5 securityd[78] <Error>:  CFPropertyListReadFromFile file file:///Library/Keychains/accountStatus.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)
Nov  6 23:19:04 LHD-iPod5 securityd[78] <Error>:  CFPropertyListReadFromFile file file:///Library/Keychains/accountStatus.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)
Nov  6 23:19:04 LHD-iPod5 securityd[78] <Error>:  CFPropertyListReadFromFile file file:///Library/Keychains/accountStatus.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)
Nov  6 23:19:04 LHD-iPod5 securityd[78] <Error>:  CFPropertyListReadFromFile file file:///Library/Keychains/accountStatus.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)
Nov  6 23:19:05 LHD-iPod5 accountsd[83] <Notice>: 2013-11-06 23:19:05.058 accountsd[83:28531]: ACDClient {Name: itunesstored, Bundle ID: (null), PID: 90} is trying to verify account credentials for account: vzotest@gmail.com
Nov  6 23:19:05 LHD-iPod5 accountsd[83] <Warning>: NSScanner: nil string argument
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDPlaybackPositionStorageController]  clearing all local changes that had been scheduled for push
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDPlaybackPositionStorageController]  reseting sync anchor to 0, and scheduling pull from server
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDPlaybackPositionStorageController]  target sync date from client: 2013-11-06 17:49:11 +0000 (in 4.98 sec)
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDPlaybackPositionStorageController]  setting target date to: 2013-11-06 17:49:11 +0000 (in 62708451053.69 sec)
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDPlaybackPositionStorageController]  scheduling sync (via BackgroundTaskJob) 4.982637 seconds from now...
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDPlaybackPositionStorageController]  clearing all local changes that had been scheduled for push
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDPlaybackPositionStorageController]  reseting sync anchor to 0, and scheduling pull from server
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDPlaybackPositionStorageController]  target sync date from database: 2013-11-06 17:49:11 +0000 (in 4.93 sec)
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDPlaybackPositionStorageController]  scheduling sync (via BackgroundTaskJob) 4.934034 seconds from now...
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: {MediaLibrary} Rolling back transaction.
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDPlaybackPositionStorageController]  clearing all local changes that had been scheduled for push
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDPlaybackPositionStorageController]  reseting sync anchor to 0, and scheduling pull from server
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDPlaybackPositionStorageController]  target sync date from database: 2013-11-06 17:49:11 +0000 (in 4.87 sec)
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDPlaybackPositionStorageController]  scheduling sync (via BackgroundTaskJob) 4.870597 seconds from now...
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: {MediaLibrary} Rolling back transaction.
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDPlaybackPositionStorageController]  clearing all local changes that had been scheduled for push
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDPlaybackPositionStorageController]  reseting sync anchor to 0, and scheduling pull from server
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDPlaybackPositionStorageController]  target sync date from database: 2013-11-06 17:49:11 +0000 (in 4.83 sec)
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDPlaybackPositionStorageController]  scheduling sync (via BackgroundTaskJob) 4.832559 seconds from now...
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 accountsd[83] <Error>: TASK-ASSERT: cfurlcache - ProcessCacheTask - FAILED to get task-assertion, going commando with 1 items to process.
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: {MediaLibrary} Rolling back transaction.
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 voiced[1814] <Warning>: Error (hex)80000008 (int)-2147483640 at /SourceCache/VoiceServices/VoiceServices-225.1/Daemon/VSSpeechServer.m:1286 (destroying TTS instance)
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 medialibraryd[1586] <Warning>: {MediaLibrary} [MediaLibraryService] Cancelling any active or suspended import operations in progress for process <unknown process> (process ID = 1814)
Nov  6 23:19:06 LHD-iPod5 medialibraryd[1586] <Warning>: {MediaLibrary} [MLWriter] Cleaning up any remaining transactions for ended process <unknown process> (process ID = 1814)
Nov  6 23:19:07 LHD-iPod5 securityd[78] <Error>:  CFPropertyListReadFromFile file file:///Library/Keychains/accountStatus.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)
Nov  6 23:19:07 LHD-iPod5 securityd[78] <Notice>: item SecDbItemDoUpdate replaced O,genp,D374AF13,L,dku,apple,1233,acct,svce,v_Data,20131106174029.101178Z,5E4CDDCE with O,genp,D374AF13,L,dku,apple,1233,acct,svce,v_Data,20131106174907.148855Z,02E51650 in <SecDbConnection rw open>
Nov  6 23:19:07 LHD-iPod5 securityd[78] <Error>:  CFPropertyListReadFromFile file file:///Library/Keychains/accountStatus.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)
Nov  6 23:19:07 LHD-iPod5 securityd[78] <Notice>: item SecDbItemDoUpdate replaced O,genp,09A5666B,L,ck,apple,1234,acct,svce,v_Data,20131106174029.147905Z,0B3CA9DB with O,genp,09A5666B,L,ck,apple,1234,acct,svce,v_Data,20131106174907.195573Z,02078191 in <SecDbConnection rw open>
Nov  6 23:19:07 LHD-iPod5 backupd[1815] <Warning>: INFO: Account changed (enabled=0, accountID=(null))
Nov  6 23:19:07 LHD-iPod5 backupd[1815] <Warning>: INFO: Account changed (enabled=0, accountID=(null))
Nov  6 23:19:07 LHD-iPod5 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore: operation failed (pid: 1815 sel: 23 ret: e00002f0)
Nov  6 23:19:07 LHD-iPod5 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore: operation failed (pid: 1815 sel: 23 ret: e00002f0)
Nov  6 23:19:10 LHD-iPod5 wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[405452950.172733]: Client itunesstored set type to normal application
Nov  6 23:19:10 LHD-iPod5 wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[405452950.173567]: BG Application: Present, BG Daemon: Present. Daemons: apsd networkd sharingd 
Nov  6 23:19:10 LHD-iPod5 voiced[1817] <Warning>: {MediaLibrary} Database validation succeeded
Nov  6 23:19:10 LHD-iPod5 ReportCrash[1818] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 1806
Nov  6 23:19:11 LHD-iPod5 ReportCrash[1818] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process DentistGame[1806]
Nov  6 23:19:11 LHD-iPod5 com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.dentistgame.tooth[0xd1fe][1806]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.dentistgame.tooth[0xd1fe]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Nov  6 23:19:11 LHD-iPod5 backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.dentistgame.tooth[0xd1fe]' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
Nov  6 23:19:11 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDPlaybackPositionStorageController]  running synchronizeImmediatelyWithCompletionHandler: now
Nov  6 23:19:11 LHD-iPod5 ReportCrash[1818] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DentistGame_2013-11-06-231910_LHD-iPod5.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
Nov  6 23:19:11 LHD-iPod5 wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[405452951.855255]: Client itunesstored set type to background application
Nov  6 23:19:11 LHD-iPod5 wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[405452951.856724]: BG Application: Present, BG Daemon: Present. Daemons: itunesstored apsd networkd sharingd 
Nov  6 23:19:11 LHD-iPod5 wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[405452951.857583]: Already connected to LHD_wifi.
Nov  6 23:19:12 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: [StoreBookkeeper] [SBKTransactionController.m:457] Transaction Failed: <SBKSyncTransaction: 0x17da6dd0> SYNC: anchor=0 -- Error: <SBKStoreError:0x17ec2220> "Error Code = SBKStoreErrorCodeStoreAccountSessionExpired (-1004)"
Nov  6 23:19:12 LHD-iPod5 storebookkeeperd[1585] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDJobScheduler]  Could not synchronize domain 'com.apple.upp' (<SBKStoreError:0x17da5c30> "Error Code = SBKStoreErrorCodeStoreAccountSessionExpired (-1004)").  Synchronization will be re-attempted when the network connectivity, or account status has changed.
Nov  6 23:19:13 LHD-iPod5 wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[405452953.410312]: Client itunesstored set type to normal application
Nov  6 23:19:13 LHD-iPod5 wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[405452953.412261]: BG Application: Present, BG Daemon: Present. Daemons: apsd networkd sharingd 
Nov  6 23:19:13 LHD-iPod5 wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[405452953.577018]: Client itunesstored set type to background application
Nov  6 23:19:13 LHD-iPod5 wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[405452953.577765]: BG Application: Present, BG Daemon: Present. Daemons: itunesstored apsd networkd sharingd
```

Any help?